# using jquery .clone function on multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not the most familiar with jQuery, and this is the first time I've ever used the 'clone' function.

Basically what I'm wanting to accomplish is to have a form with multiple 'sections', each which will have an input field. I want the user to be able to add as many input fields into each section as they want. Each of these sections are dynamically created (using just a simple php loop) based on a value the user imports earlier in the process.

I have it so that the form is built, but my problem is with the user being able to add/remove the input fields for each section. I have it set so that the php loop creates an input field and 'add'/'remove' buttons for each section. The id's for these items are dynamically created based on the section #. When the button is clicked, it calls a javascript function which clones the existing input field and then updates the new fields id's so that it is unique. You can see an example of what I currently have in this JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NWGUp/2/ (please note that since jsfiddle doesn't allow php, I have just included the html for 3 sections with the id's and everything the exact same as the php loop would create). You'll see that the add buttons do not work.

If I just remove sections 2 & 3, and leave the html for section 1 and all of the javascript the exact same everything works properly as it should: http://jsfiddle.net/NWGUp/1/

So obviously the problem is all due to having the multiple 'sections', but I have no idea why since everything was setup to treat each section uniquely by its number identifier.

Any idea where I'm going wrong? I know it might be a bit confusing, so please let me know if any clarification is needed!

Thanks for your help!

Here is the javascript I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(".addClass").click(function () {
            //get ch#
            var ch = $(this).attr('param1');

            var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            var newNum = new Number(num + 1); // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

            //create var which stores the div name
            var divName = 'input' + ch + '_' + num;
            //alert(divName);
            // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
            var newElem = $('#' + divName).clone().attr('id', 'input' + ch + '_' + newNum);


            // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
            newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + ch + '_' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + ch + '_' + newNum);

            // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
            $('#' + divName).after(newElem);

            // enable the "remove" button
            var btnName = 'btnDel' + ch;
            //alert(btnName);
            // $('#'+btnName).attr('disabled','');

        });

        $(".delClass").click(function () {
            //get ch#
            var ch = $(this).attr('param1');

            var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            $('#input' + ch + '_' + num).remove(); // remove the last element

            // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
            /*if (num-1 == 1)
                  $('#btnDel'+ch).attr('disabled','disabled');*/

        });


    });
```

and html w/ all 3 sections:

```
<form id="myForm">

    <h2>SECTION 1</h2>

    <div id="input1_1" class="clonedInput" style="margin-bottom:4px;">file path:
        <input id="name1_1" type="text" name="name1_1">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="btnAdd1" class="addClass" type="button" param1="1" value="Add Another">
        <input id="btnDel1" class="delClass" type="button" param1="1" value="Remove Last">
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
            <h2>SECTION 2</h2>
    <div id="input2_1" class="clonedInput" style="margin-bottom:4px;">file path:
        <input id="name2_1" type="text" name="name2_1">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="btnAdd2" class="addClass" type="button" param1="2" value="Add Another">
        <input id="btnDel2" class="delClass" type="button" param1="2" value="Remove Last">
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
            <h2>SECTION 3</h2>
    <div id="input3_1" class="clonedInput" style="margin-bottom:4px;">file path:
        <input id="name3_1" type="text" name="name3_1">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="btnAdd3" class="addClass" type="button" param1="3" value="Add Another">
        <input id="btnDel3" class="delClass" type="button" param1="3" value="Remove Last">
    </div>
</form>
```

and html w/ only 1st section:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <div id="input1_1" class="clonedInput" style="margin-bottom:4px;">file path:
        <input id="name1_1" type="text" name="name1_1">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="btnAdd1" class="addClass" type="button" param1="1" value="Add Another">
        <input id="btnDel1" class="delClass" type="button" param1="1" value="Remove Last">
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />

</form>
```

Comment: The problem is that `$(".clonedInput")` finds all of these DIVs, not just the ones in the current section. You need to wrap each section in a DIV, then use `.parent()` to find the containing DIV of the button, and `.siblings()` to get the clonedInput elements in that section.

Comment: @Barmar--thanks for the quick and helpful reply...I should have realized that I need a unique identifier for .clonedInput so that it didn't count all of them. I didn't quite know how to implement your suggestion using .parent()/.siblings() but was able to correct it by just taking on the unique section # to the .clonedInput declaration and that fixed it. My changes can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/NWGUp/3/

Comment: Don't make up attribute names like `param1`, use `data-param1`. `data-XXX` attributes are reserved for this purpose. You can then access them with jQuery's `.data('param1')`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can get away without setting ids and names, in which case everything becomes much simpler.

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <div class="section">
        <h2>SECTION 1</h2>
        <div class="inputWrapper hidden">file path:
            <input type="text" name="name1[]" />
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="addClass" type="button" value="Add Another" />
            <input class="delClass" type="button" value="Remove Last" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <h2>SECTION 2</h2>
        <div class="inputWrapper hidden">file path:
            <input id="name2_1" type="text" name="name2[]" />
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="addClass" type="button" value="Add Another" />
            <input class="delClass" type="button" value="Remove Last" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <h2>SECTION 3</h2>
        <div class="inputWrapper hidden">file path:
            <input type="text" name="name3[]" />
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="addClass" type="button" value="Add Another" />
            <input class="delClass" type="button" value="Remove Last" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript :

```
$(function() {
    $(".addClass").on('click', function () {
        var $sect = $(this).closest(".section");
        $sect.find(".inputWrapper").eq(0).clone().show().insertBefore($sect.find(".controls"));
        $sect.find(".delClass").attr('disabled', false);
    }).trigger('click');
    $(".delClass").on('click', function () {
        var $sect = $(this).closest(".section");
        $sect.find(".inputWrapper:last").remove();
        if($sect.find(".inputWrapper:visible").length <= 1) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        }
    }).attr('disabled', true);
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NWGUp/4/)